# Configuring Cypress, cypress-react-unit-test, and React

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-4, cypress

I want to test our React components independently using the package `cypress-react-unit-test`. After several days, I have been unable to get it to work with the existing React Webpack configuration.
I get the error: `TypeError: path argument is required to res.sendFile` when I open the file through Cypress' window.

I am using the file from their example repo for testing: 
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/blob/master/examples/unit-testing__react/greeting.jsx

We do use TypeScript, but I wanted to get this working first.

I have tried overwriting `path` as it is defaulting to `undefined`, but I'm getting the same error.

```
{
  options: {
    path: "/my/home/dir/"
  }
}
```

In my `cypress/plugins/index.js` file I have:

```
const wp = require("@cypress/webpack-preprocessor");

const webpackConfig = require("../../node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpack.config")("development");

module.exports = on => {
  const options = {
    webpackOptions: webpackConfig
  };

  on("file:preprocessor", wp(options));
};
```

I'm obviously missing something, but I don't know Webpack well enough. I would be grateful for any pointers! Thanks!

Comment: What versions of cypress and react-scripts?

Comment: The latest as I just installed it yesterday.  To be specific though:
react-scripts = 2.1.8
cypress = 3.2.0

Comment: if it's possible please attach your existing  React Webpack configuration

Comment: Did you end up solving this? I'm experiencing the same error with a different setup.

Comment: I didn't unfortunately. I took a different approach and have the component loaded in Storybook, then I use Cypress to test against Storybook's URL. It turned out to be a win-win as Storybook is a fantastic tool.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue as well, this is how my issue was resolved.

Paste the following code in your `plugins/index.js` file

```js
module.exports = (on, config) => {
    config.env.webpackFilename = './cypress/webpack.config.js' // or path to your webpack.config.js
    require('cypress-react-unit-test/plugins/load-webpack')(on, config)
    return config
}
```

Add the following in your `cypress.json` file

```js
"componentFolder": "cypress/component"
```

Add this import in your `support/index.js` file

```js
import 'cypress-react-unit-test/support'
```

Create a folder under the Cypress folder with the name of "components" and write place your test files there.
Now run Cypress.

Comment: could you help please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71517597/cypress-and-cucumber-reset-the-requests-in-next-js

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports = (on, config) => {
   config.env.webpackFilename = 'path/to/your/webpack.config.js';

   // load-webpack is the main key here
   require('cypress-react-unit-test/plugins/load-webpack')(on, config);

   // IMPORTANT to return the config object
   // with the any changed environment variables
   return config
}
```