# Cypress and Cucumber reset the requests in Next Js

Tags: javascript, next.js, cypress

I am using in my next js application cypress to test a page. I need to test 2 scenarios: 1. Success and 2. Bad when user receives an error.

```js
Before(() => {
  return void cy.server()
});

// first scenario
Given('the user access app', () => {
  ...
});

And('the user make request', () => {
  cy.route('GET', `${api}/cars`, 'fixture:good').as('goodRequest');
});

Then('the user should see good answer', () => {
  cy.get('[data-cy=ok]').should('exist')
})

//second scenario
Given('the user access app', () => {
  ...
});

And('the user make request', () => {
  cy.route('GET', `${api}/cars`, 'fixture:bad').as('badRequest');
});

Then('the user should see bad answer', () => {
  cy.get('[data-cy=bad]').should('exist')
})
```

The first test pass, but when the second starts, i anyway get the previous response from the first request and get on the page the good response and test fails because the bad text does not appear on the page.
 Is there a solution to reset the response after each test or something like this? How to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `cy.route()` to send requests, use `cy.request()`.

```js
And('the user make request', () => {
  cy.request('GET', `${api}/cars`).as('goodRequest');
});
```

Comment: also i have a question, adding this: And('the user make request', () => {
  cy.route('GET', `${api}/cars`, 'fixture:good').as('goodRequest');
});  , should i do also `cy.wait('@goodRequest');` or wait here is redundant?

Comment: It kind of depends on the test , but probably not because this line has built in waiting and retrying - `cy.get('[data-cy=ok]').should('exist')`.

Comment: But I just noticed it's wrong - you need `cy.request()` not `cy.intercept()` or `cy.route()`.

Comment: using request, how to return a response like using route from fixtures?

Comment: It's not clear what you are testing. Use `cy.request` to test the api, use `cy.intercept` to test the front end. In your sample I don't see where the front end triggers the call. It should be in `And('the user make request', () => {` - please explain how user makes the request?

Comment: i test front end

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243065/discussion-between-asking-and-fody).